# issue with the ng-options not working in a simple array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-select

I want to save the selected value and pop up the selected value . But when I add the ng- change directive the select stops functioning. If you remove the ng change the droplist is displayed. Help me out.

This is my html

```
<div ng-app="HelloApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>Term</p>
    <select ng-model="bob" ng-change="test()" ng-options="x for x in nos">

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my js script

```
**var app = angular.module('HelloApp', []);  
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
console.log('ctrl working');
    $scope.test = function () {
     nos=["5", "10", "15"];**
     var kill=$scope.bob;
     alert ("changed!"+ kill); 
    }

});
```

I am new to angular and internet searches only land to complex arrays not a simple one. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Change your script to the following :

```
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', []);  
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
console.log('ctrl working');
$scope.nos=["5", "10", "15"];
    $scope.test = function () {

       var kill=$scope.bob;
       alert ("changed!"+ kill); 
    }

});
```

Things to note :

-The `nos` must be declared into the controller scope , previously it was not visible to the view.
-It should be out of the test function.

Answer (score 1):

See this - 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkwb2hv1/)

```
$scope.nos=["5", "10", "15"];
$scope.bob="";
$scope.test = function () {
   alert($scope.bob);

}
```

Comment: hey got it, thnks

Answer (score 0):

Just a Bit change , nothing major

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.nos=["5", "10", "15"];
    $scope.test = function (x) {
     alert (x); 
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="bob" ng-change="test(bob)" ng-options="x for x in nos">
```

Thanks

Comment: ya, got it, thnks for answering so fast